# scanf skipping string with a defined size with a proceeding space

Tags: c++, scanf, c-strings

I'm trying to read 3 different strings of max 15 characters each. When I try to read them with `scanf("%s %s %s", a, b, c)`, only the last one is picked up (I'm asuming the spaces between every string has something to do with this).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define DIM 15

int main()
{
    char a[DIM], b[DIM], c[DIM];

    scanf("%s %s %s", a,b,c);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << "Cadenes introduides: " << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}
```

the input is `CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars`

And I'm only seeing

```
CadenaDe15chars
Cadenes introduides:   CadenaDe15chars
```

when the actual output should be

```
CadenaDe15chars
CadenaDe15chars
CadenaDe15chars
Cadenes introduides: CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars
```

I'm kinda new to c++ so I don't really know how to make scanf ignore the whitespace, I've found examples with strings delimited by a new line `\n`, but not with a space.

Comment: `#define DIM 15` is not large enough to hold 15 characters plus the end of string `\0`.

Comment: *Too-Short-By-1* failure. Also note `"%s %s %s"` is equivalent to `"%s%s%s"`. The `"%s"` format specifier discards leading whitespace on its own. (the bitter issue is why are you using `scanf()` in C++ when `std::cin` or `std::getline()` are preferred.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp is there any way I can ignore \0 so I can safely store the 15 characters with scanf? or I should code a function to read the input until I get a \0?

Comment: No. C-style strings require it. Why not use the C++ `std::string`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sadly it is an uni assignment and I have to use char[x]

Comment: Then use a sufficiently sized buffer. `#define DIM 256`. Never skimp on buffer size. And if using `scanf()` you must use the *field-width* modifier to prevent against buffer overrun `"%255s %255s %255s"`. Otherwise, `scanf()` with `"%s"` is no safer than `gets()` -- See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can't increase the size of the array in this context

Comment: You can try `scanf("%14s %14s %14s", a,b,c);` but data can get lost.

Comment: Don't use unnecessary macros. Use variable for this.

Comment: Then `"%14s %14s %14s"` will protect an array of 15 chars by limiting the number of characters written to 14 plus the nul-terminating character. You can also use [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) but note the conditions where `failbit` will be set if `count` is set.

Comment: Give the teacher what they want so you can pass the class, but note this isn't how real-world C++ programmers will solve the problem unless facing significant resource constraints.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah I know, honestly programming classes on an scenario like this usually differ from actual real world code.

I'm trying to read char by char, since %14s is actually making me lose characters for some reason

Comment: That's what `%14s` does. It prevents a user from <expletive deleted>ing up the program by trying to stick too many characters in too small a space by stopping and dumping excess characters. Never trust a user. The ones that aren't trying to hack your program for fun and profit are dropping typos.

Comment: You can read char-by-char but it won't help when it comes to printing the strings. `cout` will print chars until it finds a `\0`. That's how it knows to stop. If your array does not have that you may get unexpected results. You _must_ either increase the buffer size or lose characters. Or, I guess, print the strings char-by-char as well.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp "*`cout` will print chars until it finds a `\0`. That's how it knows to stop*" - more accurately, `cout` itself doesn't care about `'\0'` at all, it is the overloaded `operator<<` that takes in a `const char*` which needs `'\0'`.  You can use `cout.write()` instead to work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call

```
scanf("%s %s %s", a,b,c);
```

invokes undefined behavior because at least this input "CadenaDe15chars" contains 15 characters. So the appended terminating zero character '\0' will be written by the function outside the corresponding array used as an argument.

You should at least declare the macro constant like

```
#define DIM 16
```

to reserve space in the arrays for potentially appended zero character.

Comment: I can't increase the size of the string in this scenario. It must be 15 characters, how can I ignore the terminating \0 safely?

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY In this case either the arrays will not contain strings or the input strings will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Given your constraints (no 0-termination), I would read the input char-by-char, adding them to an appropriate array and processing white-space character to go to the next array.

Note that the array `char a[DIM]` does NOT have to be 0-terminated. However, you won't be able to use it and a C-string APIs, including `cin << ...`

Code example. You can read a line into the `std::string` variable first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int DIM = 15;

int main()
{
    char a[DIM], b[DIM], c[DIM];
    int a_len(0), b_len(0), c_len(0);

    std::string s = "CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars CadenaDe15chars";

    int ind = 0;
    for (; a_len < 15; ++a_len, ++ind) {
        if (std::isspace(s[ind]))
            break;
        a[a_len] = s[ind];
    }
    while (std::isspace(s[ind]))
        ++ind;

    for (int i = 0; i < a_len; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Repeat for `b` and `c`, or use two-dimensional array.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is what I need. I've been trying to read char by char from stdin but I can't manage to do it. Do you happen to have an example on how to do this?

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY please see my code example above.